# Can't implicitly convert type string to int ISSUE

Tags: c#

Here is my code in C#
The problem is in the get properties. When I try to return it shows me that it cannot convert type string to `int`!
I tried to look for the problem still yet no solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DefiningProperties
{
    class BookPrices
    {
        private string Name;
        private int MarketPrice;
        private int Sale;
        private string Aouther;

        public int price
        { 
            get
            {
                return MarketPrice * Sale;
            }
            set
            {
                MarketPrice = value;
            }
            }

        public int BookDispay
        {
            get
            {
               strong text return Name + ", " + price + ", " + Aouther;
            }
        }

            public BookPrices(string bName, int bMarketPrice, int bSale, string bAouther)
        {
                Name = bName;
                MarketPrice = bMarketPrice;
                Sale = bSale;
                Aouther = bAouther;
        }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: In particular, what do you think `int BookDispay` means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property is of type `int`, but you are trying to return a `string`.

Comment: `price` will be implicitly converted.

Comment: any object used with the string concatenation operator '+' is handled by the framework to be converted to an empty string if the reference is null or to obj.ToString() otherwise.

Comment: The anwer changed accordingly :) I used .net a while ago, but i remember having to explicitly cast, did this change in some version of .net or was it like this always?

Answer (score 0):

Just change From

```
public int BookDispay
```

to This

```
public string BookDispay
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** You don't have the private `string` field `bookDisplay`.

**Solution:** you need to create a private string field `bookDisplay` and then write the public property to set and get the values into private `bookDisplay` field.

Try This:

```
class BookPrices
{
    private string bookDisplay; //add this private field.
    public string BookDispay    // now create a public property here
    {
        get
        {
          bookDisplay = Name + ", " + price + ", " + Aouther;
          return bookDisplay ;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: what is     `private string bookDisplay;` for ?

Comment: The problem you mentioned is irrelevant. You are changing the requirements.

Comment: That makes no sense. You can now set `bookDisplay`, but `BookDispay`'s getter will never return it.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi That's better, but now the field `bookDisplay` is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You are Wrong in Signature Of Properties

You Declared it as `Int` and Returns a `String`

Replace `Int` With `String`